# Image not rendered in Sitecore GlassMapper

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

I am using GlassMapper in Sitecore Webforms, and i want to render  image, but image is not rendering.

here is my code:

```
 <% using (BeginRenderLink(x => x.LogoLink, isEditable:true))
   { %>
    <%=RenderImage(x=>x.SiteLogo) %>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure, you using appropriate Model use like as:

```
     <%= RenderImage(x => x.Image, isEditable: true) %>
```

if your are not able to fix your issue, try also

```
<%= GlassHtml.Editable(Model, x=> x.Image, x=> GlassHtml.RenderImage(x.Image))  %>


<%= Editable(x=> x.Image, x=> GlassHtml.RenderImage(x.Image))  %>
```